# d3 axis sits in [0,1] domain

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am drawing a simple (4 options) radar chart with d3.
But even with manualy defined scale my axis draws on domain [0,1] both in terms of pixel size (length) and labeled numbers.

Here is the code:

```
var scl = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 100]);
var x1Axis = d3.svg.axis(scl);

d3.select('#radarWrapper svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (height/2) + ")")
  .call(x1Axis);
```

this draws a stupid one-point scale in the center of svg, without any relation to defined scale:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale to use is not set as an argument to the constructor to `d3.svg.axis()` (it doesn't take any arguments), but through the [`.scale()` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#scale):

```
var x1Axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(scl);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5tzf6xak/).